# Need to reduce PyInstaller artifacts

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyinstaller

I am building application with `PyInstaller` and get a lot of artifacts in `dist/app` folder:

- MSVCP90.dll
- MSVCR90.dll
- msvcrt.dll
- pyside-python2.7.dll
- python27.dll
- pywintypes27.dll
- QtCore4.dll
- QtGui4.dll
- QtNetwork4.dll
- QtWebKit4.dll
- shiboken-python2.7.dll
- user32.dll
- yaml.dll
- App.exe
- App.exe.manifest
- _ctypes.pyd
- _hashlib.pyd
- _socket.pyd
- _ssl.pyd
- _yaml.pyd
- bz2.pyd
- pyexpat.pyd
- PySide.QtCore.pyd
- PySide.QtGui.pyd
- PySide.QtNetwork.pyd
- PySide.QtWebKit.pyd

I am already OK to deliver all `DLLs`, but not sure that I want to deliver all `pyd-files`.

How can I reduce deliverables :)?

Comment: `.pyd` files are also libraries, just like `.dll`s. If you want your app to work, you'll need to redistribute everything.

Comment: ok, but how can I avoid deliver eggs folder?

Comment: are you using network\webkit features?

Comment: Yes, `http` and `ftp` connections

Comment: Looks like the best solution is described here - http://unafaltadecomprension.blogspot.com/2014/07/pyinstaller-separating-executable-from.html

Answer (score 0):

When using pyinstaller make sure you add the argument onefile:

```
C:\YourDir> pyinstaller --onefile yourscript.py
```